# CMD outputs in the same txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, output

I have a batch file with multiple commands:

> XCOPY C:\File_path C:\Destination
>
> RENAME C:\File_path New_name
>
> DEL C:\File_path

I need them to write the outputs in the same text file. In this way at the end of the process I have txt file with all the procedure and I can check if everything has been done correctly.
I tried with the following command after each single command/step:

> command 1> output.txt 2>&1

but it rewrites the file. It does not keep the output of all the steps but just the last one. How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MS you probably should be using the "append" operator - `>>`.

This is the article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx

Answer (score 2):

use append operator. It will append your output to existing file. Instead of overwriting it.

```
command 1 >> output.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside batch file, command by command

```dos
    >  output.txt 2>&1 xcopy ...
    >> output.txt 2>&1 rename ...
    >> output.txt 2>&1 del ...
```

`>` will overwrite/create the text file and `>>` will append to it

Or, wrapping commands inside a block

```dos
> output.txt 2>&1 (
    xcopy ...
    rename ...
    del ...
)
```

Or, outside batch file

```dos
myBatchFile.cmd > output.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append to a .txt file, you should use  `>>` instead of `>`